# SED: removing block of lines if condition is met?

Tags: json, sed

Is it feasible to remove a block of lines (including starting `{` and ending `},`) only if `"is_staff": true`?

The text file content would be always in this format:

```
[
{
  "model": "accounts.account",
  "pk": 2,
  "fields": {
    "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$320000$5vD4W5YDuvMmyyVRN5ub6U$weJzPTlN1Hrd7dlpjeO2Lw29a8ej+60Ib09vEifi4Qk=",
    "last_login": "2022-09-08T14:20:45.106Z",
    "is_superuser": false,
    "licence": "dde0af69-154a-4b8c-b393-bd59730b5947",
    "email": "account_admin@bk.ai",
    "first_name": "Marco",
    "last_name": "Rossi",
    "piva": "02375050511",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_staff": false,
    "date_joined": "2022-09-07T14:10:22.456Z",
    "groups": [
      1
    ],
    "user_permissions": []
  }
},
{
  "model": "accounts.account",
  "pk": 1,
  "fields": {
    "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$320000$mh3UDxtwhiROEecrz8XH3o$NmqWo9epps2EQnYYTe8bKm72HqfHImxUE/eVSZWQ/1U=",
    "last_login": "2022-09-09T13:54:09.498Z",
    "is_superuser": true,
    "licence": null,
    "email": "admin@bk.ai",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "piva": "",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_staff": true,
    "date_joined": "2022-09-07T14:05:03.213Z",
    "groups": [],
    "user_permissions": []
  }
},
{
  "model": "accounts.account",
  "pk": 3,
  "fields": {
    "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$320000$n4PRBAgTo8AejcTf66LTEr$SxhmWFvIcf+gWDyzNXpWz0MrfjemaX1a2msBxUZNvBc=",
    "last_login": null,
    "is_superuser": false,
    "licence": "dde0af69-154a-4b8c-b393-bd59730b5947",
    "email": "account_viewer@bk.ai",
    "first_name": "Alessandro",
    "last_name": "Bianchi",
    "piva": "",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_staff": false,
    "date_joined": "2022-09-07T14:11:39.207Z",
    "groups": [
      3
    ],
    "user_permissions": []
  }
},
{
...
}
]
```

Preferred result:

```
[
{
  "model": "accounts.account",
  "pk": 2,
  "fields": {
    "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$320000$5vD4W5YDuvMmyyVRN5ub6U$weJzPTlN1Hrd7dlpjeO2Lw29a8ej+60Ib09vEifi4Qk=",
    "last_login": "2022-09-08T14:20:45.106Z",
    "is_superuser": false,
    "licence": "dde0af69-154a-4b8c-b393-bd59730b5947",
    "email": "account_admin@bk.ai",
    "first_name": "Marco",
    "last_name": "Rossi",
    "piva": "02375050511",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_staff": false,
    "date_joined": "2022-09-07T14:10:22.456Z",
    "groups": [
      1
    ],
    "user_permissions": []
  }
},
{
  "model": "accounts.account",
  "pk": 3,
  "fields": {
    "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$320000$n4PRBAgTo8AejcTf66LTEr$SxhmWFvIcf+gWDyzNXpWz0MrfjemaX1a2msBxUZNvBc=",
    "last_login": null,
    "is_superuser": false,
    "licence": "dde0af69-154a-4b8c-b393-bd59730b5947",
    "email": "account_viewer@bk.ai",
    "first_name": "Alessandro",
    "last_name": "Bianchi",
    "piva": "",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_staff": false,
    "date_joined": "2022-09-07T14:11:39.207Z",
    "groups": [
      3
    ],
    "user_permissions": []
  }
},
{
...
}
]
```

Comment: It's probably possible but I recommend using `jq` instead. `jq` is especially created to parse/manipulate Json.

Comment: `sed` cannot be used to process JSON for various reasons: the JSON can be represented on multiple lines or on a single line, the order of keys can differ, some characters can be encoded or escaped etc. Use a tool specialized in processing JSON, like `jq` (https://stedolan.github.io/jq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have now changed the format of your input to actual JSON, it is much simpler and more reliable to use a json-aware tool such as `jq`:

```
jq '[ .[] | select(.fields.is_staff!=true) ]' <infile >outfile
```

This will pretty-print, so output will be indented differently from the input sample. However, it does not change the meaning of the JSON.

Comment: I found out myself a solution along this lines using `jq` as well. Does this work as well? `jq 'map(select(.fields.is_staff != true))' infile`

Comment: @Barnercart they are exactly equivalent. `jq` defines `map` as: `def map(f): [.[] | f];`

Comment: Sadly `jq` still does not support in-place edits tho. I end up using `yq` which supports it and is compatible with most of the `jq` features.

Answer (score 0):

Sed solution:
`sed -n '/^{/ , /^,}/ { /^{/ h; //!H; /^},/ { g ;/is_staff": true/d; //!p } }' file`

From `{` to `},` accumulate in hold space.

On `},`:

- `g` to get the hold space into pattern space
- `/is_staff": true/d` to delete pattern space
- `//!p` to print it otherwise

Comment: How would you change it by supporting it like a JSON array? I've updated the question since it was missing the array starting and ending character `[ ]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '
    /^{$/ { # start of stanza - reset hold
        h
        d
    }

    # accumulate
    H

    /^},$/! d # next if not end of stanza

    # end of stanza - delete if match, else print
    x
    /"is_staff": true/ d
' file
```

Comment: How would you change it by supporting it like a JSON array? I've updated the question since it was missing the array starting and ending character `[ ]`.